# How to create a task group with parameterized Azure Resource Manager connection field?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to create a task group where Azure Resource Manager Connection is filled with a parameter:

[image]

However, this is not possible to do in portal as a validation force to fill it with working value. So I tried to export the task group as `json` and them modify it and import but then I got this message saving release pipeline:

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this? I understood that this is security check (which btw doesn't work in yaml pipelines becauce there you can use Azure Reource Manager connection even if you not allowed). However, in this way it limits usage of task group to a single connection.

EDIT:

**Kevin** thank you for your anser. I tired it but it didn't work for me.

So I have the connection `rg-the-code-manual`:

[image]

I created a variablewith it:

[image]

But when I tried to use it I have a validation error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my test, when I set the variable as the `Azure Resource Manager Connection` name, I could reproduce the same issue.

For example:

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to set the **variable value** in release pipeline.

[image]

Then you could save the release pipeline successfully.

On the other hand, you could also set the default value for the variable in Task Group.

[image]

In this case, the task group will use the default value in release pipeline. And the parameter will also exist in the task group task, you could directly select the value in the drop downlist.

[image]

Note: you need to make sure that the Service connection name is valid.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried but it didn't work for me. Can you check my update and help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej. Don't worry. From the screenshot, it seems that the variable name has some issue. Based on my test , if the variable name contains `-`, I get the same issue. You may try to use `$(arm)`  instead of `$(arm-connection)`as the variable name.

Comment: `-` what is wrong with you!? It worked with a variable without a dash. I assume that this is a bug, right. I must admit that one of the funniest. @Kevin-Lu-MSFT you are awesome. Thank you for your help!

Comment: variables with - in the name aren't very common